Communicate with Graph API of Tenant A from runbook in Tenant B
I have two tenants A & B. I wanted to manage the user groups in Tenant A.
I have a PowerShell runbook in Tenant B, I wanted to connect to Tenant A from the runbook.
Is that possible? If yes, how can we achieve it?

It is possible, but not use manage-identity, You should use Microsoft Entra ID service principal, such as Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $TenantId -Credential $Credential. docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/azure-powershell-login-service-principal. After login, then get access token use Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://graph.microsoft.com/"
